# Generate PDF thru TCPDF on button click - PHP

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

Good day.

I have just downloaded the TCPDF library and I want to use it but I can't figure out how to.

I have a form where a user will be filling in, I have a submit button that's being used to insert into the database thru ajax.

I want to have another button which, when clicked, it will generate the PDF for viewing.

I could use some examples and a lot of advice.

Thank you very much.